# StreamBuilder triggers a method twice while the same operation as a variable triggered only once

Tags: flutter, rxdart, stream-builder

I have a StreamBuilder that accepts a stream from my service. It looks like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: MyService.getStream$()
  builder (...)
);
```

Plus, I have my service with the following method:

```
getStream$() {
  print('being printed twice');
  return Observable.just('text')
    .doOnData(() => print('being printed twice too'));
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following `prints` being printed twice (each).

But, when I  change the following implementation as a variable, it runs just once:

```
Observable getStream = Observable
  .just('text')
  .doOnData((data) => print('being printed once');
```

Of course, in the example above, I would use variables, but in my original code, I'm unable to do so because I'm depended on the instance properties.

What I can do, is to declare an `Observable` variable and in the constructor to set it to my desired observable. Although, this solution sounds like a workaround, and I'm not sure why would the the method would be triggered twice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` is rebuild every time build method is invoked. It means that `MyService.getStream$()` is evaluated with each invocation and creates new Observable. If you assign Observable to variable it will be created once and reused between build calls.

Take a look at this question [Future running twice because it's in build method, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717335/future-running-twice-because-its-in-build-method-how-to-fix-it/58717588#58717588)
it's about future but the mechanism is same.